# How to create a generic function with write_json and read_josn using C++ boost library

Tags: c++, json, boost, c++14

I am using different functions and when executing each function, I would like to create Json message for communication like as shown below:

```
TestFunction1(string id)
{
    "message" : "MSG_TestFunction1",
        "id" : "1212"
}

TestFunction2(string id)
{
    "message" : "MSG_TestFunction2",
        "id" : "1213"
}
```

In this scenario, i am thinking that it doesn't require to maintain a .JSON file as we can create the json messages in the functions itself (like in TestFunction1 and TestFunction2 etc).

By considering all these i created the below sample using BOOST library with write_json and read_json.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include<string>

using namespace boost::property_tree;
using namespace std;

bool TestFunction1(std::string f_id)
{
    ptree strTree;
    ptree subject_info;
    ptree array1;
    array1.put("message", "MSG_TestFunction1");
    array1.put("id", f_id);
    
    subject_info.push_back(make_pair("", array1));

    stringstream s;
    write_json(s, array1);
    string outstr = s.str();

    stringstream stream(outstr);
    ptree strreadTree;
    try {
        read_json(stream, strreadTree);
    }
    catch (ptree_error& e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    TestFunction1("1212");
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Is this the correct way to create and parse the json data?
Also Please help me how to create a generic function or a class with write and read json to make use of all the functions like TestFunction1, TestFunction2 etc to create and parse the json data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the code at the top of your question meant to be? It isn't valid C++, nor is it valid JSON.

Comment: Once the TestFunction1 is executed, it creates the JSON message like {"message" : "MSG_TestFunction1", "id" : "1212"} similarly for TestFunction2, TestFunction3, etc.. And then we can send this serialized JSON message to the other application.

For that reason, for reference I mentioned the required JSON message format i am expecting in the functions (TestFunction1, TestFunction2..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, do not use Property Tree as a JSON library.

Boost 1.75.0 added a JSON library though!

As the other commenter said, it's not very clear what exactly you require, so let me just sketch a few similar use-cases:

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for compiler explorer
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace json = boost::json;

json::value TestFunction(std::string const id) {
    return json::object{
        {"message", "MSG_TestFunction1"},
        {"id", id}
    };
}

int main() {
    for (auto id : {"1212", "1213"}) {
        json::error_code ec;
        auto jsonString = serialize(TestFunction(id));
        auto roundtrip = json::parse(jsonString);

        std::cout << roundtrip << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zhz897ocP)**

```
{"message":"MSG_TestFunction1","id":"1212"}
{"message":"MSG_TestFunction1","id":"1213"}
```

### BONUS

Note that, unlike Property Tree, you have types, which means the IDs don't have to be strings:

```
for (auto id : {1212, 1213}) {
    std::cout << json::object{{"message", "MSG_TestFunction1"}, {"id", id}}
              << std::endl;
}
```

Prints ([Live Again](https://godbolt.org/z/89KEh5f3M)):

```
{"message":"MSG_TestFunction1","id":1212}
{"message":"MSG_TestFunction1","id":1213}
```

Comment: Thank you @sehe, for the detailed explanation.  I have a doubt, Once the JSON message is created using the "serialize", Is the line "auto roundtrip = json::parse(jsonString);" converts and encrypts into a json object. Because the variable "roundtrip" is showing the value in a different format.

Comment: My requirement is, when executing different API functions for this application (like TestFunction1 is executed, it creates the JSON message like {"message" : "MSG_TestFunction1", "id" : "1212"} similarly for TestFunction2, TestFunction3, etc.. And then we can send this serialized JSON message to the other application. For that reason, for reference I mentioned the required JSON message format i am expecting in the functions (TestFunction1, TestFunction2..)

Comment: "Because the variable "roundtrip" is showing the value in a different format" - where is it even showing? If you mean the output after `std::cout << roundtrip;` obviously: that's the JSON text. It's not normal for a JSON library to output C++ code, neither is JSON valid C++ code (this again [was already remarked by the other commenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843886/how-to-create-a-generic-function-with-write-json-and-read-josn-using-c-boost-l/66857075?noredirect=1#comment118177864_66843886))

Comment: I think you have all the "moving parts" you could need. Of course, it's trivial to add a more generic function that creates messages by different names:  https://godbolt.org/z/rEEcGY8hG